# Toggle md-button class on click event

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-material2

I want to use button as a selector, i have a toggle function on click event to get the value from the button click, now what i want to do is to show the user that the button is selected. That is i want to toggle class between md-primary and md-warn.

This is my button

```
<md-button  class="md-fab" ng-click="getTime(0);" 
  value="0" aria-label="midnight" ng-class="{'active': 
  variable,'disable': !variable}">0</md-button>
```

This is the controller part

```
 $scope.getTime = function (value) {
        $scope.variable = !$scope.variable;
        if($scope.variable){
            console.log(value);
        }
    };
```

Comment: Please use the [tag:angularjs-material] tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update `ng-class` like below:

```
<md-button  class="md-fab" ng-click="getTime(0);" 
  value="0" aria-label="midnight" ng-class="{'md-primary': 
  variable,'md-warn': !variable}">0</md-button>
```

also make sure to add `ngMaterial` to your app module dependencies

here is working [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/sW24rzKiX3HydQtrQJV2?p=preview) hope it make it more clear for you.

Comment: Worked! Thank you